# Run bundle install inside a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, git, bundler

I'm building a Ruby script to loop through a number of directories, and run git commands and `bundle install` on all the directories:

```
dirs = ['~/code1, ~/code2, ~/code3]
dirs.each do |dir|
  Dir.chdir(dir) do
      `git checkout develop`
      `git pull`
      `bundle install`
  end
end
```

When I do this, git is run in the correct directory, but bundler is running in the same directory as the script.

I've tried to use bundler's `--path` option, but that wasn't getting the job done either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it because `BUNDLE_PATH` is not set? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/6770468/6309). Or try http://stackoverflow.com/a/19975893/6309.

Answer (score 7):

Your `bundle install` subprocess may be inheriting an existing Bundler environment, which would cause unexpected behavior.

From Bundler's documentation:

> Any Ruby code that opens a subshell (like system, backticks, or %x{}) will automatically use the current Bundler environment. If you need to shell out to a Ruby command that is not part of your current bundle, use the with_clean_env method with a block.

Therefore, I would try this:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  `bundle install`
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as VonC said.  I needed to add the BUNDLE_PATH env var.